# Is it necessary to take care of long data type in program that is written for Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++

According to cpp reference in 64 bit systems:

```
    LLP64 or 4/4/8 (int and long are 32-bit, pointer is 64-bit)
        Win64 API 
    LP64 or 4/8/8 (int is 32-bit, long and pointer are 64-bit) 
        Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, Mac OS X)
```

Then how to consider long data type for codes which is written for Linux and Windows?

Comment: depends on exactly what you're doing with that data. ...

Comment: The question seems unclear. The language standard guarantees that `long` is at least 32 bits; you can't portably count on more than that.

Comment: *"is it necessary to take care"*, *"how to consider"* -- Could you be less vague please?

Comment: @Keith Thompson , read comments in Answer , may it will help you to understand question

Comment: No, the question itself needs to be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In C and C++, in portable code, you never know the exact size of a type like `int` or `long int`.  If you move your code to a different compiler (or a different machine, or a different OS), the sizes of some of your types may change.  This needn't be a problem; in fact it's only a problem if you want to make it a problem.  (All of this has always been the case, and has nothing to do with someone's definitions of "LLP64" and "LP64" architecture families.)
2. On those (hopefully rare) occasions when you need a type of an exact size, one good way is to use types like `int32_t` and `uint64_t` from `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>` in C).
3. But you really, really shouldn't need to specify the exact size of a type, most of the time.  (There are those who say you need to specify the exact size of every type, but my advice is to ignore those people.)
4. Pretty much the only time you need to specify exact sizes is when trying to define a structure which you can read and write in "binary" fashion to conform to some externally-imposed storage layout.  But there, specifying the exact sizes of data types isn't generally sufficient, because of issues like alignment, padding, and byte order.  So you're better off writing explicit serialization and deserialization code anyway (or using "text" data formats instead, if you can get away with it).
5. My bottom line is that I rarely worry about the exact sizes of types.

Comment: Im not talking about C , here consider your program is pure C++

Comment: @tobi303 Didn't notice the C++ tag at first, answer updated.

Comment: We should [prefer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) `<cstdint>` to `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: If it's C++, you should use `#include <cstdint>`

Comment: Whenever arithmetic and value range limits can be a issue, than you should care about size.  There are portable ways (e.g. <cstdint>) to ensure exact or minimally-required precision for your data, so you should not be ashamed of using them when you think you need to.

Comment: then why  Fixed-width integers are introduced in  C++ 11

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, that's what `int_least32_t` is for. `int32_t` is guaranteed to be 32 bits, and if the platform doesn't support a 32 bit type, then `int32_t` doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley dang it.  confused myself there.

Comment: @user5905343 the fixed width types are [provided only if the implementation directly supports the type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). This doesnt sound very portable, thus the argument that portable code should ignore the exact size of a type is still valid.